# Having a PlanningEntity inside another class

Tags: optaplanner

I'm looking to solve a problem very similar to the Project Job Scheduling example provided by optaplanner [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2zweB9JD7c&lc=z12rehaiyoemytu4o04cdpqxpxiicdmqiz40k) (I didn't find any code related to that example - if it exists it would help me a lot).

I have designed the solution using 3 classes.

- I have the `Project` class, which contains a date before which it cannot start, a name, and a list of `Task`.
- The task is my `PlanningEntity` and contains an id, name, duration, list of previous tasks and a required resource type.
  Its `PlanningVariable`s are a start date and a `Resource`.
- A resource can represent a person or tool and has a defined type.

My `PlanningSolution` is defined as such :

```java
@PlanningSolution
public class TimeTable {

    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "resourceRange")
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    private List<Resource> resourceList;

    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "startRange")
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    private List<LocalDate> dates;

    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "projectRange")
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    private List<Project> projectList;

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    private List<Task> taskList;

    @PlanningScore
    private HardSoftScore score;

    // ...
}
```

---

This design allowed me to write my constraints easily (*a task can't start before its previous ones are finished ; a task is assigned the correct resource ; a resource can't be assigned to different tasks on the same day ; minimize the time between two tasks*), but the tasks contained in my `Project` class have not changed after solving.
Only the tasks in the global `taskList` will have their `PlanningVariable`s set correctly.

How can I remedy that ?

I have thought about making the project a `PlanningEntity` as well, but it really doesn't have any variable to plan inside. I also looked at shadow variables but as I understood it this is not what they are used for.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your domain model correctly, each project contains a subset of all the tasks. This assignment of tasks to projects is fixed.
If you are saying these `project.taskList`s don't show any changes after solving, while the `taskList` located in the `TimeTable` does, I would check what instances of `Task`s the `project.taskList`s contain. All these `project.taskList`s should point to the `Task` instances from the `TimeTable.taskList`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For now, it is actually the other way around : `TimeTable.taskList` is created using all the `project.taskList`s. But in the end, it doesn't matter, does it ? What I think is happening is that Optaplanner creates copy of the tasks in `TimeTable.taskList` when solving, but I might be wrong.

Comment: It does, there is solution cloning involved during the solving. If your problem is related to cloning, it's worth checking your `Task`'s `equals` and `hashcode`; according to [1], the already cloned `Task` instance should be reused. The `equals` and `hashcode` must be stable - in the case of a planning entity, it must never include the planning variable field(s).

[1] https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-core/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/core/impl/domain/solution/cloner/FieldAccessingSolutionCloner.java#L249

Comment: I had not implemented `equals` or `hashCode` at all. Now that I did, the behaviour did not change. The project's tasks are still untouched and only the `TimeTable` have the solved ones.

Comment: Sunder, in which way can the solver be using the @ValueRangeProvider with id "projectRange" for its moves ? And if it can and does (use that @ValueRangeProvider), are the Projects then containing `Task` instances that are part of the `@PlanningEntity` instances you're stepping over ? Something tells me there's some weird hack in your model. I just can't identify what ...